# How to Remove empty rows from array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Using Alasql to read excel data. The issue is the array might contains all key with null value, My question is: How to delete rows or records, if all key has null value?

### Below is my array data:

```
[
0:{Name:"ABC1",No:5,BalanceDue:5000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"2",Date:"06/01/2018"}
1:{Name:"ABC2",No:6,BalanceDue:6000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"3",Date:"05/02/2018"}
2:{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null}
3:{Name:"ABC3",No:7,BalanceDue:7700,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"8",Date:"15/02/2018"}
4:{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null}
5:{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null}
6:{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null}
]
```

### Expected result:

```
[
0:{Name:"ABC1",No:5,BalanceDue:5000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"2",Date:"06/01/2018"}
1:{Name:"ABC2",No:6,BalanceDue:6000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"3",Date:"05/02/2018"} 
2:{Name:"ABC3",No:7,BalanceDue:7700,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"8",Date:"15/02/2018"} 
]
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `const newArr = arr.filter(i => i.Name);`

Comment: Please add some code.
Besides that; loop through the rows and check with an if-statement if the value is not null.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just add a where clause in your Alasql query to not read in the blank rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` with `array#every` to filter out object with all the values as `null`.

```js
var data = [{Name:"ABC1",No:5,BalanceDue:5000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"2",Date:"06/01/2018"},{Name:"ABC2",No:6,BalanceDue:6000,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"3",Date:"05/02/2018"},{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null},{Name:"ABC3",No:7,BalanceDue:7700,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:"8",Date:"15/02/2018"},{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null},{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null},{Name:null,No:null,BalanceDue:null,Notes1:null,Notes2:null,CurrencyId:null,Date:null}],
  result = data.filter(o => !Object.keys(o).every(k => !o[k]));
console.log(result);
```